# cURL SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, curl, php-curl, laravel-9

I have an article posting dashboard website, I send a cURL request from the website that I want to show the article on to the dashboard and it returns data, this is the code I'm using:

```
public function articleData(Request $request, $text){
        $host1 = request()->getHost();
        $host = str_replace('www.', '', $host1);
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://somedomain.com/getData?host=$host&artURL=".strtolower($text),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        ));
        $article = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $articles = json_decode($article, true);
        return view('Pages.articleTemp')->with('articles', $articles[0]);
 
}
```

the issue I'm facing is that when I uploaded it to a live server it stopped returning data which made the website throw an error.

I've tried using this

```
print curl_error($curl);
```

it returned this error:
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

I tried using these inside cURL array:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
```

nothing worked

it is working perfectly on localhost, this is only on the live server.

Comment: You'd need to _disable_ those curl options.

Comment: And in general you really should not use a self signed certificate on a production site! Why should you? Certificates are free these days.

Comment: @arkascha I think more curl option are needed.  Some of these are superfluous but they do no harm. ` CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,`  is necessary.  `CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',` is a W3C best practice. `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,` is a good thing to always include.  Redirects are common.

Comment: @Misunderstood More it not always better. There is little sense in using all sorts of directives if you do not actually need them. One sets a specific option if it is required only.

Answer (score 0):

These options disable SSL

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
```

You likely need to use the `URLOPT_CAINFO` option or a certificate directory can be specified with the `CURLOPT_CAPATH` option

This is not a big deal.  It's more of a personal pet peeve.
While GET is a valid parameter for `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`
It will work but the PHP manual says:

> A custom request method to use instead of "GET" or "HEAD" when doing a
> HTTP request. This is useful for doing "DELETE" or other, more obscure
> HTTP requests.

Use `CURLOPT_HTTPGET=>true,`

You may need to use urlencode() on the URL if they use any characters that violate the generic URI syntax as defined in *RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax* 
An Example

```
urlencode($text);
```

I see `$request` is passed to your function
I do not see any `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`
I see you defined $host which should be in the HTTP Request Header

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: $host";
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>$request,
```